# Blank document library until Item is searched

Tags: 2010, document, hidden

I have a document library which I have setup a HTML Form Web Part with connections so I can now search (filter) for documents.

However I want the list of documents to be hidden until the correct name is searched for then it should be displayed. I can't use CSS as the document searched for will not be displayed either.

Does anyone have a solution to this please?

I am using SP 2010 by the way

Answer (score 1):

why do you use the list view at all?

simply make a new site, place a search and a searchresult Webpart on it and edit the query to search in the title (or path) of the files only.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some JavaScript instead.

Check if the search field is empty on page load. If it is, hide all the items shown on the page. If it is not, the user must have done a search, so don't hide the items.